# Добавить оценку товара в битриксе

Tags: php, битрикс

необходимо добавить оценку товара на карточку, нашел "решение", добавить код в шаблон компонента

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:iblock.vote","stars",Array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arItem['IBLOCK_ID'], //ID инфоболка
        "ELEMENT_ID" => $arItem['ID'], //ID товара
        "ELEMENT_CODE" => $arItem['CODE'], //код товара
        "MAX_VOTE" => "5",
        "VOTE_NAMES" => array("0","1","2","3","4"),
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "3600"
    )
);?>
```

однако на карточке выходит сообщение "Фотография не найдена"
[image: снимок]

Comment: а куда вы вставляете? проверьте существует ли у вас шаблон "stars" и привидете полный пример шаблна template.php

Comment: вставляю в шаблон карточки товара. Привести шаблон stars? Или iblock.vote?

Comment: Шаблон самой карточки, где вызывается этот компонент, при чем тут "Фотография не найдена"  ? ничего не понятно

Comment: ссылка на шаблон https://github.com/javelinex/php/blob/master/template

Comment: код вставлял на 525 позицию в коде, перед разделом "поделится с друзьями". PS добавил скрин в текст вопроса